# Google Sheets Query & Indirect Formula

Tags: google-sheets-query

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically update a section of my google query taking a value from another cell.

I'm filtering my query with a date, e.g. `WHERE A Date > TODAY()-10`

What I'm trying to do is have a value in a cell (P1), and have my today()-10 take the number from P1 and use that in today()**-10**

So if in cell P1 I put the value 20

my query would update to today()**-20**

I've tried using indirect, and also just referencing the cell but can't get either to work:

My latest attempt without indirect is:

=query(query('Data - Google GA'!$A:$H,"SELECT B, SUM(C), SUM(D), SUM(E), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(G)/SUM(E) WHERE A >= **DATE '"&text(today()-"'&'"P1&"'&'","yyyy-mm-dd")& "'** GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(E) DESC LABEL B 'Campaign', SUM(C) 'Impressions', SUM(D) 'Clicks', SUM(E) 'Cost', SUM(F) 'Sales', SUM(G) 'Revenue', SUM(G)/SUM(E) 'ROAS'",1),"SELECT * WHERE Col7 < 3.5",1)

I've created a simplified version here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FL5suHAnKYzeW7TVja52o-6TfAmBPhNpBcKGPOjLUw/edit#gid=0

In cell N4 I've added the formula I was trying.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this (in your example file) will work:

```
=query(A:F,"select sum(B), sum(C) where A > date '"& Text(today()-P1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",1)
```

Comment: That's great thanks, worked perfectly! I'll know in future not to try and over complicate it! I was so lost in it I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks